# How can I search for interactions between users?

Tags: support, search

Can I view all questions/answers who involve more than one user?

I can view myself or a specific user

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A7294900

But not for multiple by IDs:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3684479+user%3A7294900

Nor by username:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A7294900+theyuv

Is there any way to see, for example, a question asked by user X and answered by user Y?

Comment: [How deep can the dive into user's interaction data be?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179427)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Search doesn't support multiple "user" parameters.

You can use Data.SE. [This helpful query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/25355/have-we-met) created by "Benjol" 8 years ago should be good enough, even if it could return some false positives in cases where a username is common enough.

Comment: Extremely useful, helped me quickly find some old references I needed in a flash. Thanks to you and @Benjol